# jquery choose every element from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I don't know how to achieve it and I been looking for ways to do this for hours without any success.

Let's say I have this code:

```
var vara="bing.com"; 
var varb="google.com"; 
jQuery('a[href^="http://'+vara+'"],a[href^="https://'+vara+'"]').click(function() {alert('y'); });
jQuery('a[href^="http://'+varb+'"],a[href^="https://'+varb+'"]').click(function() {alert('y'); });
```

And what I need to achieve here is to use one call that sets up the .click functions for each array variable:

```
var varall=["bing.com","google.com"];
jQuery('a[href^="http://'+varall+'"],a[href^="https://'+varall+'"]').click(function() {alert('y'); });
```

But this doesn't work. How to make variable "varall" take every element from array, so the second script would work as the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evan Trimboli's answer is OK but... In this case this selector sintaxis is not very good. Because, as I know, when jQuery will add event to `<a>` it will split a string and loop every element (again). So we get double looping.

I think the best option is to do something like this:

```
var varall=["bing.com","google.com"];

varall.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="http://' + item + '"], a[href^="https://' + item + '"]', function() {
        alert('y');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lfjy2Lxu/

Comment: Any sort of performance "gain" from this would be negligible to the point where it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're looking to do this

```
var varall=["bing.com","google.com"];

$.each(varall, function(index, value){
    jQuery('a[href^="http://'+value+'"],a[href^="https://'+value+'"]').click(function() {alert('y'); });
});
```

Comment: This would add each selector twice.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli `http` **!=** `https`